# Get HttpResult using the JsonServiceClient

Tags: servicestack

I am returning HttpResult from one of the rest service methods using servicestack's new API. Is there a way to get the HttpResult using the JsonServiceClient?

For ex: `JSonServiceClient.Send<HttpResult>("DELETE","person", new { PersonID = 30 });`

I want to inspect the header information from the httpresult.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as a `HttpResult` client response from a ServiceStack web service.

You use a `HttpResult` to customize the HTTP Response that's returned from your service, e.g. Add additional HTTP Headers. But the response body the client sees is still only the **Response DTO** (if any).

Use fiddler, wireshark, chome web inspector (if this is an Ajax call) or something like ServiceStack's [Request Logger plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) to inspect the HTTP traffic.

#### Invalid use of ServiceStack's REST Clients

Also consider using the appropriate Clients REST API like `client.Delete()`, `client.Get()` etc instead of overloading the `T.Send()` method (which is usually a POST).

Use Typed DTOs in the ServiceClient instead of anonymous types which are not supported.

#### Inspecting HTTP Headers using the ServiceStack Service Clients

ServiceStack's Service Clients provide [Local](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/ServiceClientBase.cs#L313) and [Global](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/ServiceClientBase.cs#L61) WebResponse (and Request) filters that you can use to introspect the WebClient's HttpWebResponse returned for that request, e.g:

```
client.ResponseFilter = httpRes => {
   httpRes.Headers.. //do something with returned headers
};
client.Delete(new Person { Id = 30, ...});
```

Comment: The http result looks good on fiddler which is what I use to test my services. Was curious if the servicestack client will be able to see the result. I wanted to inspect the header via code. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I've updated the answer to include an example of accessing the returned headers using the service clients.

Comment: In REST it is pretty common to do a Post request and have a response with 201 and Location header returned with no body. ServiceStack promotes avoiding HTTP. Am I right?