# Auto-generating a WebRequest

Tags: rest, web, client, servicestack

I am trying to consume a binary stream from a ServiceStack service, as described here:

[How to consume a file with a ServiceStack client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134667/how-to-consume-a-file-with-a-servicestack-client)

I realize that I must use a custom WebClient, since I want direct access to the response stream. However, I would still like to avoid making this client by hand. Instead, I'd like to write something like,

```
var webClient = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl)
                .ConfigureWebClient(new MyRequestDto { Foo = "bar" }));
```

This way, I wouldn't have to assemble the URL and query string by hand; and when I change my request DTO, I wouldn't have to remember to change my custom WebClient setup code, either.

Is there a way to accomplish this, somehow ? I've looked at `ServiceClientBase.PrepareWebRequest(...)`, and it does a whole lot of useful stuff that I don't feel like copy/pasting into my own code. I'd love to inherit `ServiceClientBase` and call that method directly, but it's private, so I can't. Anyone got any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

All of [ServiceStack's C# Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) have both a Global and a Local Request Filter allowing you to initialise the Request and Global and Local Response Filters allowing fine-grained access to the returned HttpWebResponse.

Initializing the WebRequest of all ServiceClients using a Global Request Filter:

```
ServiceClientBase.HttpWebRequestFilter = httpReq => ConfigureWebClient(httpReq);
```

Using the Local Request Filter:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl) {
    LocalHttpWebRequestFilter = httpReq => ConfigureWebClient(httpReq)
};
```

Although if you just want the binary response All Service Clients allow you to specify either a `string`, `byte[]`, `Stream` or `HttpWebResponse` as your Generic Response type and it will return what was requested. See the [Service Client wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) for more examples of these.

Here's how you can retrieve binary responses:

```
byte[] responseBytes = client.Get<byte[]>("/poco/World");
var dto = responseBytes.FromUtf8Bytes().FromJson<PocoResponse>();
```

Or with a Stream:

```
using (Stream responseStream = client.Get<Stream>("/poco/World")) {
    var dto = responseStream.ReadFully().FromUtf8Bytes().FromJson<PocoResponse>();
}
```

Or from the underlying HttpWebResponse:

```
HttpWebResponse webResponse = client.Get<HttpWebResponse>("/poco/World");

using (var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
    var dto = sr.ReadToEnd().FromJson<PocoResponse>();
}
```

#### You can change Open Source Software, you don't have to work around it

ServiceStack is Open Source software, there's no need to look for hacks or try to work around something that's not accessible or not available, make a pull-request to change what you want and if it's a valid request for a common use-case it will likely be accepted. Otherwise feel free to take a fork of the Source code and customize it as you wish.

Comment: I tried the pattern described on the page you linked: `Stream response = client.Get(new Streams { Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });`  but it didn't work. The return value is always null, though I know (via the debugger) that the service is receiving the request and returning a working `IStreamWriter`, who does write to the stream correctly. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, ask a new question or link to a standalone gist with a failing test. The Stream response works fine in the [integration tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/ServiceClientsBuiltInResponseTests.cs#L230) no idea why it's not working for you.

Comment: Is the Stream response supposed to work for any request DTO that implements `IReturn<Stream>`, regardless of what the response DTO is like ? The only difference between my code and the integration tests is that my response is an `IStreamWriter`, not a regular DTO.

Comment: I've added an example using a [StreamWriter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f4e3b5c3de78b06928be91eb821a23821975dce5) and it works as expected. I'm no longer able to help you without a failing unit test I can repro. Raise an issue with a failing unit test on GitHub if you want anyone to spend further effort chasing this.

Comment: I tried reproducing this bug, and somehow it worked this time. I have no idea why, and I'll keep checking, but it's probably a problem elsewhere. I want to accept your answer, but I'm not sure if the paragraph regarding filters is relevant, since the core answer is simply this: "Although if you just want the binary response all service clients allow you to specify either a string, byte[], Stream or HttpWebResponse as your Generic Response type". Could you edit the answer to move the filter section to the bottom, just for clarity ?

Comment: Most of this question is dedicated to how to configure and prepare the WebRequest, which using filters is exactly the answer for and is also what Google searches are going to hit since that's what you've dedicated most of your question to asking (and what both of your code samples are about). I've then listed ways to access the response bytes which was the other question asked.