# How to use an optional int parameter using ServiceStack Route with a POST request?

Tags: c#, servicestack

This works fine, and I am able to omit Speed parameter:

```
[Route("/speech/sentence/", "POST")]
public class Sentence : IReturn<HttpResult>
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public string Speed { get; set; }
}
```

This does not work, gets an 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' not able to omit Speed parameter:

```
[Route("/speech/sentence/", "POST")]
public class Sentence : IReturn<HttpResult>
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public int    Speed { get; set; }
}
```

This also does not work, gets an 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' not able to omit Speed parameter:

```
[Route("/speech/sentence/", "POST")]
public class Sentence : IReturn<HttpResult>
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public int?    Speed { get; set; }
}
```

Anyone?
Thanks

Comment: What version of ServiceStack are you using?  I tried your second DTO (the one with string/int) and it worked fine.  Speed just defaulted to zero since it wasn't a nullable-int.  Maybe show your Service that utilizes the DTO as well.  Are you using any filters?

Comment: Note `IReturn<T>` [should never return HttpResult](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13297627/85785) it should return the typed body of the HttpResult instead.

Comment: Using ServiceStack.4.0.40